# How to share data and methods between activities and widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

In my Android project I have an Activity and a Widget (Broadcast Receiver). Both have a simple button. When either of the buttons is clicked, the same action should be executed:
First of all, a Boolean variable should be set to it's opposite value (true to false, false to true). This Boolean should be stored independently from both the Activity's and the Receiver's life cycles.
Then, depending on the Boolean's old state, one of two methods should be executed to query a SQLite Database.

I need something like a Singleton Activity, which has its own Shared Preferences and methods and can be called from various Activities / Receivers.

What would be the best way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't sound like anything you want to do requires an activity. I would just write a POJO singleton with a private constructor and a static getInstance() method that returns a reference to a private static instance of the class itself, after initializing it if needed.

Then you can have an instance method that toggles the variable and fires off an AsycTask or whatever to do your query. The state of the boolean can be stored in a private instance variable, or persisted to SharedPreferences depending on how long it needs to be retained.

Comment: What exactly is a POJO Singleton? Google Search just gave me results for Java Enterprise Application, but i have not found any Android References.

Comment: Nothing about this particular idea is specific to Android. It would just be a plain class that inherits from java.lang.Object, like in this first example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html

Comment: @RafaelBankosegger POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object